# Linear Prediction and Linearity of CEF

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear, conditional-expectation

I am revisiting the basic notions of linear regression and stumbled upon the following idea in Cameron and Trivedi's Microeconometrics book:

> However, for the conditional mean to be linear in x, so that $E[y|x] =
>  α+xγ$, requires the assumption that $E[u|x] = 0$, in addition to $E[u] =
>  0$ and $Cov[x,u] = 0$.

They way I thought about linear prediction is that it is the same as the conditional mean (or conditional expectation function) if that is actually linear (otherwise it is still the best *linear* prediction) . What I fail to understand is how exactly $E[u|x]=0$ guarantees that the conditional mean $E[y|x]$ is linear.

What if the underlying distribution is non-linear? The conditional mean should be non-linear as well. How does $E[u|x]=0$ change that? Is this somehow related to the idea of omitted variables in the actual estimation (e.g. via OLS)?

Comment: Maybe this example helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190703/non-linear-endogeneity/190800#190800

Comment: Thank you. If I understand it correctly, the confusion was that I did not see that $E[u|x]=0$ is an assumption implying linearity of the CEF. Should that assumption not hold true, we would still have (at least) the best linear predictor. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, OLS is a consistent estimator of the best linear projection of $y$ on $X$. Omitted variable considerations come into play once we start worrying if that linear projection also corresponds to an underlying structural model that we hope to be able to give a causal interpretation.