# If $Y=X\beta + e$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Xe]=0$ then $\mathbb{E}[X^2e] = 0$

Tags: econometrics, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to determine whether the above statement is true or false, and provide a short proof. My instinct is that this is false, and I just need a simple counterexample.

Comment: Please make $X$ and $x$ consistent.

Comment: ... and clarify your notation.  Is "$X$" a random variable or not?  Does "$Xe$" refer to a scalar or perhaps a dot product?  Are these expectations conditional on $X$ or not?  What additional assumptions are you making about $e$?

Comment: Counterexample: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190703/non-linear-endogeneity/190800#190800

Comment: Fixed lowercase $x$, sorry was late at night. I believe it can be assumed that $X$, $e$, $Y$ and $\beta$ are all scalars.  $X$ and $e$ are both random variables.

Comment: Perhaps it is as simple as a counterexample like letting $e = \frac{1}{x}$...

Comment: Thanks Christoph.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with $Y,$ so why mention it in the title?  This suggests you haven't formulated the question you really want to ask.